# Is Holoviews able to fill missing dates with 0 in plot?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, holoviews

I have a simple bar plot with aggregated timeseries data as value. The variable on the x-axis is formatted as Datetime and interpreted correctly by Holoviews. Y-Axis displays the aggregated count of observed events during the day.

Is it possible to add an option to Holoviews, that will leave "empty bars" for the missing days that are not part of the observed data? Because there were no events on that particular days. In according to my screenshot, there should appear bar with a height of zero for 2017-06-23 and 2017-06-25 until 2017-06-28.

[image: Holoviews]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Barcharts are for plotting categorical data** (with not too many categories)

 You have timestamps, so normally a lineplot or scatterplot would be better for plotting longer periods.


Here's **2 possible solutions for bar charts**:

**1)** You could **use .redim.values()** to specify which specific categories you would like to have on your x-axis:

```
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dates': [pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 1), pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 3)],
    'values': [30, 10],
})

# specify which categories you would like to show
# if you need a long list, better use a for loop to generate list
new_date_values = [
    pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 1), 
    pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 2), 
    pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 3),
]

# use redim.values() to specify which categories you would like to show
bar_plot = hv.Bars(df)
bar_plot.redim.values(dates=new_date_values)
```

**2)** But maybe **even simpler is modifying your df**:

* **setting your dates as the index** of your dataframe and
* **then do [df.asfreq('D')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) from pandas**.

Asfreq('D') makes sure that every date will appear in your index.

```
# set dates as your index and use .asfreq('D)
df = df.set_index('dates').asfreq('D')

bar_plot = hv.Bars(df)
bar_plot
```

**Resulting plot:**

[image: bar plot also including dates that aren't present in data (so that are 0)]